# JQGrid remove cell value from custom error message in inline editing

Tags: jqgrid, inline-editing

I am new to `JQGrid`. I want to customize validation while inline editing in jqgrid for that i have used editrules: `{ custom: true, custom_func: functionabc}.` 
This displays validation message as

> [Cell Value] This is test validation.

How to avoid displaying "Cell value" in alert?

Comment: which version of jqGrid/free jqGrid/Guriddo jqGrid JS you use? Which editing mode (cell editing, inline editing or form editing) you use?

Comment: Hi Oleg,  I am using jqGrid  4.4.4 - jQuery Grid(free). I am using inline editing. To make grid inline edit i have used editformbutton: false,editbutton: true in formatoptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is old and well known. It's fixed in version 4.5.3 (and all later versions). I don't recommend you to use old version if you don't want to see old bugs.